# String conversion issue with string variable in subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, string-formatting

I am quite bad with subprocess.
I am having issues with my bottom line, subprocess.call, getting the source and destination variables to work.

```
import subprocess, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", '--path_to_torfs', type=str)
parser.add_argument("-w", '--path_to_wips', type=str)
parser.add_argument("-n", '--number_in_each_wip', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

source = args.path_to_torfs
destination = args.path_to_wips


subprocess.call(['sudo', 'mv', '`ls %s -v1 | head -2`', '%s' % (source, destination)])
```

My error is:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `subprocess.call` you provide a list of 4 strings, the 3rd one has one placeholder but no arguments and the 4th has also one placeholder and two arguments.
The solution is to provide the arguments on the proper place:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'mv', '`ls %s -v1 | head -2`' % (source), '%s' % (destination)])
```